# Comment traduire « touchy » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais

Parfois professionnellement dans le domaine de l'informatique, j'entends le mot « touchy » pour désigner quelque chose de classe, d'à la mode (en parlant d'une animation sur un site par exemple).

1. Comment traduire ce terme en français dans ce contexte ?
2. Est-ce que l'emploi de ce terme est restreint au domaine informatique ou non ? L'avez-vous déjà entendu avec ce sens dans un autre contexte ?

À noter que je ne parle pas ici de la traduction littérale du mot en français (*délicat, épineux, susceptible*).

Édition : visiblement, personne n'a jamais entendu ce mot dans ce contexte, sûrement un mot mal utilisé par une ou deux personnes.

Comment: Dans la deuxième question tu cherches à connaître l'étendue de l'emploi du mot anglais dans la langue française ?

Comment: « On entend le mot « touchy » » tu ferais bien de présenter un exemple si tu en as un sous la main.

Comment: Dans la deuxième question, je cherche à savoir si le mot est utilisé ailleurs que dans le domaine informatique. L'avez-vous déjà entendu et dans quel context ?

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez: il me semble avoir donné un exemple.

Comment: @Zistoloen, Je pense que vous avez confondu l’orthographe française de *contexte* avec celle de l’anglais, (context) donc je l’ai épelé autrement.  Je crains néanmoins fort que je me suis trompé, pensant que vous utilisez l’orthographe anglaise pour désigner une chose particulière. Avertissez-moi si c’est le cas.

Comment: Je pense que vous faite reference au terme "techy"... lorsqu'on parle de choses assez pointues, techniques

Answer (score 5):

Comme traduction littérale de "touchy" j'utilise plutôt le terme français « sensible » (qui a en français le double sens « délicat », « douloureux » et que l'on peut « toucher », « voir » grâce aux sens).

Le terme est largement utilisé hors du domaine informatique.

Dans le contexte de l'usage du mot dont tu parles, que je ne connaissais pas (dans quel contexte l'a tu entendu ?), je traduirais plutôt "touchy" par sujet « chaud » voire « brûlant », qui insistent surtout sur l'aspect récent (pas encore froid), mais avec aussi une connotation de danger que tu ne désire peut-être pas. Une autre possibilité pourrait être « classe » ou « classieux » un peu familliers, mais moins que « qui pète » « qui en jette » ou «qui claque» évoqué dans une autre réponse.

Answer (score 3):

Cela me semble une déviation de sens, et n'évoque rien d'autre en français que les propositions (plus : ombrageux, proche de susceptible), en anglais britannique du moins, **sauf** :

**démonstratif** (dans un sens plutôt psychologique) ou **qui aime le contact physique** (souvent précisé par *touchy-feely*).

Peut-être une extension régionale de sens, voire argot limité à une grande entreprise ? Dans le sens "qui vous interpelle" , je suggérerais "**convaincant**", "**persuasif**", "**démonstratif**" (cette fois dans un sens intellectuel) mais il n'y a aucune idée d'être à la mode dans ces termes. Dans celui de "pas à prendre avec des pincettes", "**délicat**".

---

Ce terme est extrêmement courant dans les sens indiqués dans la question, et celui supplémentaire de ma réponse. Pas un Britannique ne l'ignore. Exemples :

"Don't oppose his views, he is very touchy" = Ne le contredisez pas, il est très chatouilleux" [intellectuel].

"Bucephalus was very touchy" = (Le cheval préféré d'Alexandre) était très ombrageux.

"This issue is touchy" = Cette difficulté est délicate.

"He was very touchy in his plea" = Il montra beaucoup de sensibilité / fut très convaincant dans son plaidoyer.

Mais :

"Don't tickle his feet, he is ticklish" = Ne le chatouillez pas, il est chatouilleux [physique].

Answer (score 2):

1. Je ne connaissais pas ce terme dans le monde de l'informatique, mais d'après la description que tu en donnes, ça pourrait se traduire par *léché* (limite soutenu), *qui claque* (familier)
2. Je ne saurais répondre à cette question...